# How can I uninstall ubuntu and then install windows 8.1

Tags: uninstall

I want verification that my windows 8.1 instalation disk will run if i uninstall ubuntu

Comment: Right now are you able to use both Ubuntu and Windows 8 without any problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Using disk management tool in windows, delete volumes where you have installed Ubuntu
2. Put Windows 8 installation disk and restart the computer. Go to BIOS/UEFI settings by pressing F10 or F12 at the boot time and choose `boot from removable media`
3. Chosee Repair your computer -> Troubleshoot -> Advanced options -> Command prompt
4. At the command prompt type: `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`
5. Restart your computer and boot from hard disk.